# How to install Xcode plugin for Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: xcode, windows, visual-studio

Some developers have told me about it's possible to create iOS projects in Microsoft Visual Studio thanks to an Xcode plugin.

However, I can't find the proper way to install it, I already have tried to download it from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sterin.xcodebuild-tools) and I installed it but it doesn't appear when I try to create a new project.

So, if anyone can tell me the steps I have to follow in order to install the plugin properly, it would great.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean Xamarin ios? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/

Comment: I'm not sure if it's Xamarin, anyway I have looked at its documentation and a MacOS is required and I have been told to get rid of my Virtual Machine with MacOS if I use Visual Studio instead.

Comment: You downloaded plugin for visual studio code which is a different IDE

Comment: Yes, I had to install Visual Studio Code but I thought it was just an extension for the regular IDE. So, a macOS will be needed for this or not?

Comment: This plugin doesn't support iOS app developing, it is only useful for macOS apps. Also you can't create new project using this plugin, you can only work with existing project. So I think it is not what you need.
If you want to develop native iOS applications you need macOS and xCode. No options.

Comment: Well, in fact I just want to continue building the app I am building on Xcode, but on Windows because using a VM with MacOS is pretty slow, but well, I will continue using the VM I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The xcode build tool you're trying to use has still a lot of issues and only few workflows are being implemented and supported. I suggest that if you wanted to create cross platform application and would like to use Visual studio code IDE then i suggest on using Xamarin its code base is c#. If you're using a mac computer then why not use xcode and if you're a windows user and wanted to create iOS apps then xamarin would be the best choice for you or unless you want to try frameworks like ionic etc. I hope i was able to help.Also , I can't comment because of still low repu , so I decided to post this as answer.

Comment: Thank you Jelord! Yes, someone has already told me about Xamarin, but it is not possible to code in Swift then? Only in c#? I don't think I'm interested if so, I already have a Virtual Machine with MacOS and I'm using Xcode in there but I want to get rid of my VM because it's pretty slow and it's using a lot of space from my disk considering that I have a 255GB SSD.

Comment: Yeah just c#. Yeah that is the problem on VM its slow , how much more when you're building and submitting the app to app store or using emulator . welcome , i hope my answer helps. Also can you please mark the answer if it helps you :D , I am building reputation so I can access comment as for now.

Comment: If you really wanted to try swift and objective c then it would be better for you to get a mac hehe

Comment: Ah well, I can't change to C# because the app I'm building is in Swift and I wouldn't like to rewrite all the code I have, so I will continue using a VM then.

And of course, your answer has helped me so I'll mark it :) Thank you!

Comment: Just a tip bro , when using VM use a real device in testing the app instead of a simulator . Simulator will make the machine more slow. Thank you.

Comment: Alright! I did not know it. Thank you for the the tip :)